# tensorflow execution freezes for a small CNN

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run some simple convolutional NN in tensorflow in Windows 10 with 40GB memory, using the CPU version. However, so far I keep running into trouble with the execution either hangs right after initializing variables or after a few training iterations. Below is a summary of my code and what I want to achieve.

I have in each image a five-letter sequence, and I would like to train the CNN to recognize the sequence in each image. To do this I have two convolution layer (height/width/channel: 4/4/5, 4/4/10) each fed into a relu layer, followed by two fully connected relu layers, and finally a softmax layer with cross-entropy loss function.

```
num_image = 5
image_size = (28, 150)
out_channel = 5;
shape_conv1 = [4, 4, 1, out_channel]  # height, width, in_channel, out_channel
stride_conv1 = [1, 2, 2, 1]
shape_conv2 = [4, 4, out_channel, out_channel*2]  # height, width, in_channel, out_channel
stride_conv2 = [1, 2, 2, 1]
num_layer1 = 100
num_layer2 = 100

num_output = 10
num_batch = 200

size_intermediate = [1, np.ceil(np.ceil(image_size[0]/stride_conv1[1])/stride_conv2[1]), \
                 np.ceil(np.ceil(image_size[1]/stride_conv1[2])/stride_conv2[2]), out_channel*2]
size_trans = [int(i) for i in size_intermediate]

with graph.as_default():
    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_batch-num_image+1, image_size[0], image_size[1], 1])
    input_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [num_image, num_batch-num_image+1, num_output])
    reg_coeff = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    weights_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape_conv1, 0.0, 0.1))
    bias_relu1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([out_channel]))
    weights_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape_conv2, 0.0, 0.1))
    bias_relu2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([out_channel*2]))
    weights_layer1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(\
                        [num_image, size_trans[1]*size_trans[2]*size_trans[3], num_layer1], \
                        0.0, (num_layer1)**-0.5))
    bias_layer1 = tf.zeros([num_image, 1, num_layer1])
    weights_layer2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_image, num_layer1, num_layer2], \
                        0.0, (num_layer2)**-0.5))
    bias_layer2 = tf.zeros([num_image, 1, num_layer2])
    weights_output = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_image, num_layer2, num_output], 0.0, num_output**-0.5))
    bias_output = tf.zeros([num_image, 1, num_output])

    output_conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_data, weights_conv1, stride_conv1, "SAME")
    output_relu1 = tf.nn.relu(output_conv1 + bias_relu1)
    output_conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(output_relu1, weights_conv2, stride_conv2, "SAME")
    output_relu2 = tf.nn.relu(output_conv2 + bias_relu2)

    shape_inter = output_relu2.get_shape().as_list()
    input_inter = tf.reshape(output_relu2, [1, shape_inter[0], shape_inter[1]*shape_inter[2]*shape_inter[3]])
    ## One copy for each letter recognizer
    input_mid = tf.tile(input_inter, [num_image, 1, 1])

    input_layer1 = tf.matmul(input_mid, weights_layer1) + bias_layer1
    output_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(input_layer1)
    input_layer2 = tf.matmul(output_layer1, weights_layer2) + bias_layer2
    output_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(input_layer2)
    logits = tf.matmul(output_layer2, weights_output) + bias_output

    # Training prediction
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, input_labels))
    # Loss term for regularization
    loss_reg = reg_coeff*(tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_layer1)+tf.nn.l2_loss(bias_layer1)\
                                +tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_layer2)+tf.nn.l2_loss(bias_layer2)\
                                +tf.nn.l2_loss(weights_output)+tf.nn.l2_loss(bias_output))

    learning_rate = 0.1
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss+loss_reg)
```

The CNN is rather simple and fairly small, so I was rather surprised when I saw it froze after initializing all variables, or at best after a few training runs. There is no output of any kind, and ctrl+c would not interrupt the execution. I wonder if it could have anything to do with the Windows version of Tensorflow, but am currently at a loss where to look for clues.

Could someone share their suggestion/opinion on what may have caused my issue? Thank you!

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, there may be an issue with the way I feed data to the model. Therefore I also post that part of code below.

```
num_steps = 20000

fixed_input = np.random.randint(0, 256, [num_batch-num_image+1, 28, 150, 1])
fixed_label = np.tile((np.random.choice(10, [num_batch-num_image+1, 1])==np.arange(10)).astype(np.float32), (5, 1, 1))

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print("Initialized")
    loss1 = 0.0
    loss2 = 0.0

    for i in range(1, num_steps+1):
        feed_dict = {input_data : fixed_input, input_labels : fixed_label, reg_coeff : 2e-4}
        _, l1, l2, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, loss_reg, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        loss1 += l1
        loss2 += l2

        if i % 500 == 0:
            print("Batch/reg loss at step %d: %f, %f" % (i, loss1/500, loss2/500))
            loss1 = 0.0
            loss2 = 0.0
            print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, fixed_labels))
```

I am simply using a random input and its labels to test if the code runs. Unfortunately the execution again freezes within the first few steps of the training.

Comment: The model itself looks fine. There are two possibilites: either (a) there's something wrong with the code that feeds inputs to and runs the graph, which you don't show, or (b) there's a bug in Tensorflow on Windows. One way to work out which it is would be to try running the model with random or constant inputs, without any of your code to read inputs. Does it still hang after a couple of steps? If so, then you should file a Github issue. If not, then there's something wrong with the input-reading code --- could you show that? Hope that helps!

Comment: @PeterHawkins Thanks for the suggestion. I have posted the code I used to do the training. Unfortunately even with the constant data the training still got stuck. Unless there is something basic that I am missing, it seems I may have indeed run into some issue with tensorflow...

Comment: That does sound like a windows-specific bug to me. It sounds to me like your best bet is to file a Github issue. Please make the smallest, self-contained reproduction you can and file an issue on Tensorflow Github. (The smaller and simpler your reproduction code is, the higher the probability is that someone will fix it.)

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? I'm also using softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits on OS X and TF just freezes. Even ctrl+c doesn't help, I have to kill the process. Also, it doesn't use any CPU when frozen.

Comment: @ooxio Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution for this. I eventually switched to using docker.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to queue-runners.
Could you please try to run your training step within MonitoredSession which handles initialization and queue running under the hood. It will look like as follows:

```
with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...) as sess:
  sess.run(optimizer)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite follow. My (limited) understanding is that the queue-runners are used to feed data into the main training part. If that is the case, since I am not using queue-runners, why would they be the cause of the freeze?